# Can multiple endpoint use same CSRF token?

Tags: single-sign-on, single-page-application, csrf

I have Single Page Application(SPA) with multiple endpoints using Singe Sing On(SSO) with JWT token. I try to figure out how to initialize a CSRF token while still keeping my frontend and backend logic as simple as possible.

My question is: Is there a way to avoid generating a CSRF token for every endpoint? So can I, for example, generate CSRF token during my login process (first fetch CSRF token and rotate the token in every login request) and then verify that one CSRF token in every backend? How could this be implemented if it is somehow possible?

I use X-CSRF tokens, so on the server side the token is set to cookies, then the client duplicates it to request headers and finally server verifies that cookie and header value match. I use django csrf middleware which also does some extra validation to avoid client self generated tokens. This extra validation is something I do not really understand

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, what you have in mind is not possible. But you could communicate with a proxy that knows the other endpoints. That would make the most sense from my point of view. So you only need the CSRF token for this one endpoint. And on the server side from the proxy to your other servers you don't need CSRF anymore. But this solution means you need an additional endpoint.

Comment: Yes, thanks! That is what we maybe should do... I had already thought about implementing BFF to not exposing JWT tokens to client, handling the JWT token refresh and routing the communication between client to multiple endpoints and thus making the whole architecture more secure.

Comment: That sounds interesting. Architectural issues are an important topic at the beginning of every project. I am relatively new to architecture. But one question. If I understood your question correctly, you already have a BFF architecture, don't you?

Comment: No I do not have. Currently I have React frontend and multiple endpoints. (authenticationServer, Backend1, Backend2, etc.) I use JWT tokens with asymmetric keys, so my auth server only have a private key and thus can generate new tokens. The other servers have only a public key which with they can verify the tokens generated by auth server but can not generate a new ones.

Comment: So JWT verify and user authentication can be done by every backend but only auth server can generate new tokens and log in users. 

I store JWT tokens in cookies (Secure, httponly, samesite). 

With BFF, I could make a single gateway for all the traffic, manage CSRF tokens and JWT tokens there. For more info about the BFF idea and token security I recommend this excellent video https://pragmaticwebsecurity.com/talks/xssoauth.html

Comment: @Viljami Thank you for the information and the link! I will check it out. Sounds very interesting.